# Use Dependabot to update action versions when changes are made on a template repository

Tags: github, github-actions, github-dependabot

I would like to use Dependabot to create PRs when the version of actions change within the Github workflows on a template repository on all its child repos that have used the template. From the documentation, I couldn't find any relevant sections to implement this.

Note I would need the Dependabot to bump to the action versions changes in the template, not to the latest version of the actions.

I would like to be able to maintain a template and allow any action version changes to simply be spread out to all its users.

Comment: You can't use dependabot for that, but you could create a separate repository to host reusable workflows, and have all other repositories call them, so all action versions live in just a single place.